# Best way to change profile page

Tags: profiles

### What I want to do:

I want to change the profile (backend) layout. Hide and add personal fields.

### What I don't want to do:

Use some *dirty* javascript hacks to remove fields

---

Adding fields is actually not a problem. I already wrote a plugin for this.
But now I want to hide some default wordpress fields. I've researched a bit into this topic. It seems there are exactly 2 options to hide fields. Either edit `user-edit.php` or use JS/jQuery to remove fields.

**So.. What about editing `user-edit.php` and just replace/edit the file again after wordpress updates?** Doesn't sound that wrong. I guess it's not that critical. What do you think? Or is there even a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

What about just targeting with CSS?

`tr.user-nickname-wrap { display: none; }`

Of course the fields will still be in the source but the CSS targeting will be faster than JS.

You can load your WP Admin CSS this way:

```
function wse_183286_profile_admin_css() {
    $screen_id = isset( get_current_screen()->id ) ? get_current_screen()->id : null;

    if ( 'profile' === $screen_id || 'user-edit' === $screen_id ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'profile-admin-css', '/path/to/your/file.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wse_183286_profile_admin_css' );
```

Unfortunately, I don't think there are hooks provided in WordPress (yet) to remove fields in the clean way you are looking for.

Comment: Still feels *dirty*, no? Kinda too hacky imho. I feel pretty good with my custom profile page tbh. Well anyway. Didn't even consider the css way, which is obviously way better than CSS. Thank you